# how to getResultCode() from onReceiver when i no have credit on my phone

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My problem is that when my phone is no credit, the method `onReceiver()` is never called.Then my cuestion is how to get `ResultCode()` without `onReceiver()`.The `resultCode` is every time 0 when tried with `enviados.getResultCode()` ("enviados" is the `BroadcastReceiver`)

---

this is my code:

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {

    if (arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

        if (arg0.getId()==destinatario.getId()){
              finish();
              guardaTexto=textoet.getText().toString();
              Intent consola = new Intent(this,ListaContactos.class);
              consola.putExtra("guardaTexto", guardaTexto);
              startActivity(consola);
              finish();
              return true; 
        }
        else
            if (arg0.getId()==enviar.getId()){ 


                t=-1;
                s=-1;
                manager=SmsManager.getDefault();


                final String texto=recibeTexto;


                final Intent send = new Intent(SENT);
                final PendingIntent 
                        statusEnviado=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,send,0); 

                final Intent delivery = new Intent(DELIVERED);
                final PendingIntent  statusEntregado 
                        =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,delivery,0); 

                final ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new 
                            ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                sentIntents.add(statusEnviado);
                final ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new 
                            ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
                deliveryIntents.add(statusEntregado);



                enviados=new BroadcastReceiver() { 



                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context contexto,Intent 
                                    intento){


                             t++;

                             String maximo="";
                             BaseDeDatos sel=new 
           BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                             SQLiteDatabase 
           max=sel.getReadableDatabase(); 

                             Cursor cursorMax=max.rawQuery("SELECT 
      max(id) as maximo FROM conversaciones WHERE number='" + number[t] + "'",null);


                             while (cursorMax.moveToNext()){
                             maximo = 
                  cursorMax.getString(cursorMax.getColumnIndex(("maximo")));
                             }
                             cursorMax.close();
                             max.close();
                             sel.close();

                       switch (getResultCode()){

                       case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                           if (address[t].equals("No agendado")){
                            Toast 
                   enviado=Toast.makeText(contexto,"Mensaje enviado con éxito a " + 
                   number[t],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            enviado.show();
                           }
                           else
                           {
                            Toast enviado=Toast.makeText(contexto,"Mensaje 
                            enviado con éxito a " + address[t],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            enviado.show();
                           }                      
                            break;
                       case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:

                            Toast 
               noEnviado=Toast.makeText(contexto,"Mensaje no enviado a " + address[t] 
               ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            noEnviado.show();

                            BaseDeDatos db3=new 
              BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                            SQLiteDatabase 
              insertar3=db3.getWritableDatabase(); 

                            insertar3.execSQL("UPDATE conversaciones SET 
                                estado='errorEnviar' WHERE  id='" + maximo + "'"  );
                            insertar3.close();
                            db3.close();

                            break;
                       case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:

                            Toast 
                   sinCobertura=Toast.makeText(contexto,"Sin cobertura de red.El 
                   mensajes será enviado cuando" +
                                    " la red esté 
                    disponible",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            sinCobertura.show();

                            BaseDeDatos bd1=new 
              BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                            SQLiteDatabase 
              modo1=bd1.getWritableDatabase(); 
                            ContentValues registro1=new 
             ContentValues(); 

                            registro1.put("tipo","cobertura"); 

             registro1.put("address",address[t]);
                            registro1.put("number",number[t]);
                            registro1.put("body", 
             textoet.getText().toString());
                            modo1.insert("reportes", null, registro1); 
                            modo1.close();
                            bd1.close();

                            BaseDeDatos insert=new 
            BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                            SQLiteDatabase 
            escribe=insert.getWritableDatabase(); 

                            escribe.execSQL("UPDATE conversaciones SET 
                          estado='errorEnviar'WHERE  id='" + maximo + "'"  );
                            escribe.close();
                            insert.close();

                            Intent servicio = new 
                        Intent(Principal_mensajes.this, servicioEntregaYerror.class);
                            startService(servicio);


                            break; 
                       case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:

                            Toast sinServicio=Toast.makeText(contexto,"Sin 
                                servicio.El mensajes será enviado cuando " +
                                    "el servicio esté 
                               disponible",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            sinServicio.show();

                            BaseDeDatos bd2=new 
              BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                            SQLiteDatabase 
              modo2=bd2.getWritableDatabase(); 
                            ContentValues registro2=new 
              ContentValues(); 

                            registro2.put("tipo","servicio"); 

               registro2.put("address",address[t]);
                            registro2.put("number",number[t]);
                            registro2.put("body", 
             textoet.getText().toString());
                            modo2.insert("reportes", null, registro2); 
                            modo2.close();
                            bd2.close();

                            BaseDeDatos insert2=new 
             BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                            SQLiteDatabase 
             escribe2=insert2.getWritableDatabase(); 

                            escribe2.execSQL("UPDATE 
            conversaciones SET estado='errorEnviar'WHERE  id='" + maximo + "'"  );
                            escribe2.close();
                            insert2.close();


                            Intent servicio2 = new 
                       Intent(Principal_mensajes.this, servicioEntregaYerror.class);
                            startActivity(servicio2);


                            break; 
                       case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:

                            Toast saldo=Toast.makeText(contexto,"El 
                      mensaje no ha sido enviado.Podría deberse a que su saldo se ha 
                         terminado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                            saldo.show();

                            BaseDeDatos insert3=new 
              BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                            SQLiteDatabase 
              escribe3=insert3.getWritableDatabase(); 

                            escribe3.execSQL("UPDATE 
            conversaciones SET estado='errorEnviar'WHERE  id='" + maximo + "'"  );
                            escribe3.close();
                            insert3.close();

                       }

                      }

                   };



                 entregados=new BroadcastReceiver() {    

                        @Override
                        public void onReceive(Context contexto,Intent 
                                     intento){

                             s++;

                             String maximo2="";
                             BaseDeDatos sel2=new 
             BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                             SQLiteDatabase 
            max2=sel2.getReadableDatabase(); 

                             Cursor cursorMax2=max2.rawQuery("SELECT 
           max(id) as maximo FROM conversaciones WHERE number='" + number[s] + 
            "'",null);


                             while (cursorMax2.moveToNext()){
                             maximo2 = 
                       cursorMax2.getString(cursorMax2.getColumnIndex(("maximo")));
                             }
                             cursorMax2.close();
                             max2.close();
                             sel2.close();


                             switch (getResultCode()){

                               case Activity.RESULT_OK:

                               BaseDeDatos db=new 
             BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                               SQLiteDatabase 
              insertar=db.getWritableDatabase(); 

                               insertar.execSQL("UPDATE conversaciones 
             SET estado='entregado' WHERE id=" + maximo2 );
                               insertar.close();
                               db.close();

                                 break;


                              case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:

                                 BaseDeDatos db2=new 
           BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                                 SQLiteDatabase 
            insertar2=db2.getWritableDatabase(); 

                                 insertar2.execSQL("UPDATE 
          conversaciones SET estado='noEntregado' WHERE id=" + maximo2 );
                                 insertar2.close();
                                 db2.close();

                                  break;
                             }


                         }

                      };


                 registerReceiver(enviados,new IntentFilter(SENT));
                 registerReceiver(entregados,new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new 
                             AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage("Estas seguro de enviar el mensaje?")  
                .setCancelable(false)       
                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new 
                          DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
             {                


                       for(int c=0;c<number.length;c++){

                       BaseDeDatos bd1=new 
              BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                       SQLiteDatabase modo1=bd1.getWritableDatabase(); 
                       ContentValues registro1=new ContentValues(); 

                       registro1.put("address", address[c]); 
                       registro1.put("number", number[c]); 
                       registro1.put("body", textoet.getText().toString());
                       Calendar calendario = new GregorianCalendar();
                       int horas=calendario.get(calendario.HOUR_OF_DAY); 
                       int minutos=calendario.get(calendario.MINUTE); 
                       int segundos=calendario.get(calendario.SECOND); 
                       String fecha=String.valueOf(horas + ":" + minutos + ":" 
                              + segundos);
                       registro1.put("horario",fecha );
                       Time time1= new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
                       time1.setToNow();
                       String stringTime1=String.valueOf(time1.monthDay + "/" 
                              + time1.month + "/" + time1.year);
                       registro1.put("fecha",stringTime1);
                       modo1.insert("enviados", null, registro1); 
                       modo1.close();
                       bd1.close();

                       BaseDeDatos bd2=new 
            BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                       SQLiteDatabase modo2=bd2.getWritableDatabase(); 
                       ContentValues registro2=new ContentValues(); 

                       registro2.put("address", address[c]); 
                       registro2.put("number", number[c]); 
                       registro2.put("body", textoet.getText().toString());
                       Calendar calendario2 = new GregorianCalendar();
                       int horas2=calendario.get(calendario2.HOUR_OF_DAY); 
                       int minutos2=calendario.get(calendario2.MINUTE); 
                       int segundos2=calendario.get(calendario2.SECOND); 
                       String fecha2=String.valueOf(horas2 + ":" + 
                                   minutos2 + ":" + segundos2);
                       registro2.put("horario",fecha2 );
                       Time time2= new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
                       time2.setToNow();
                       String stringTime2=String.valueOf(time2.monthDay + "/" 
                               + time2.month + "/" + time2.year);
                       registro2.put("fecha",stringTime2);
                       registro2.put("envia","true" );
                       registro2.put("ordenDeEnvio",String.valueOf(c) );
                       modo2.insert("conversaciones", null, registro2); 
                       modo2.close();
                        bd2.close();
                       }


                       BaseDeDatos borra=new 
              BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                       SQLiteDatabase 
               cont=borra.getWritableDatabase(); 
                       cont.execSQL("DELETE FROM multipleContacts");
                       cont.close();
                       borra.close();

                     int length=textoet.length();

                        if (length>160){

                            ArrayList<String> parts = 
                                      manager.divideMessage(textoet.toString());

                            for(int a=0;a<number.length;a++){


   manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(number[a], null,parts,sentIntents,deliveryIntents);

                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            for(int b=0;b<number.length;b++){

                               manager.sendTextMessage(number[b], 
            null,textoet.getText().toString(),statusEnviado,statusEntregado);


                            }



                        }  


                       Intent SMS = new Intent(Principal_mensajes.this, 
                                   lista.class);
                       startActivity(SMS);
                       finish();



                }     
                })       
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new 
                             DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
                               {                
                   dialog.cancel();        
                    }

                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

                  return true; 
        }
            else
                if (arg0.getId()==cancelar.getId()){

                       BaseDeDatos borraTodo=new 
             BaseDeDatos(Principal_mensajes.this,"administradorDeMensajes", null,18); 
                       SQLiteDatabase 
             contTodo=borraTodo.getWritableDatabase(); 
                       contTodo.execSQL("DELETE FROM 
               multipleContacts");
                       contTodo.close();
                       borraTodo.close();

                       Intent lista = new Intent(this,lista.class);
                       startActivity(lista);
                       finish();

                }


    }

        return false;

}
```

Comment: Please add any source code and clearify the issue.

Comment: Probably depends on what kind of `BroadcastReceiver` it is.

Comment: Sorry.I can add the code in 8 hours after asking because my reputation isn`t high.I past the code later.

Comment: @Quino: What error message are you getting when you try to post your code?

Comment: the error is: Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

    Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 3 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

This appear when i'm clicking in button "Post Your Answer"

Comment: Andrey: the cuestion is when i send SMS and my phone have credit, the onReceiver() is called and i can get resultCode,but when my phone has no credit, the onReceive is never called and can`t get the ResultCode().How to get the resultCode in this case?

Comment: MrSnowflake: the kind of BroadcasReceiver is for sent SMS.

Answer (score 1):

Without the need for code one may conclude your application is working exactly as it should.

If your BroadCastReceiver only listens for successfully sent SMS, and you have no credit, no SMS is sent, so no Intent will ever be received, so no result code will be returned...

Comment: thanks you dmmh, your answer solve my problem.I Have a last question: there is a method returns a value in case that BroadCastReceiver never listening?Because I need get a value.Now post my code.